# Java: how to store multiple threads that handle different files

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a server, that sends different files (each opening a thread) on request.
each thread doesn't know which file hes handling on creation but only once a message with its name is received, so at that time I need to associate it with the file somehow.

I need the option to wait for all the threads of a certain file to end, and of course 
all the threads in the server.

The whole threads thing is done with a thread group, 
as for the files, I wanted to add a list of threads to each file (I have a wrapper class for it already), and add the option to wait for a certain file.
but I don't think this is a good solution, plus I need to use some concurrent collection, and I cant find anything that is just a concurrent linked list.

Any suggestion how to implement this?

Comment: I can't understand you question. What is it that you want to do? Why are multiple threads working on the same file? Are you using SSD disks? Explain what the real problem is, and not how you tried to solve it.

Comment: Are you looking for Thread.join()?

Comment: consider using java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

Comment: In short its a server that people download files from it, clients connect and download files (maybe the same file, maybe different).
Each request opens a thread (so not to lock other requests).
Then, the thread receives a request for a fileName and sends it

in the same time, there is a server console I can modify files with (rename/delete). so If i change file a.txt and 3 people are downloading it, I need the command to wait and only then change its name.

Comment: So while these 3 people download, you stop offering the file, until the last one is complete? What if the last person is very slow and will take days to complete. Will the file not be available during this time, only for the person already downloading it? You may be looking at a scenario where an abstraction layer between the file system and your application makes sense. Decoupling you from file system locks could be nessessary.

Comment: the only time the file is not offered is when its modified by the server = deleted/renamed.
if a person is very slow, then the rename command will wait for days.

Answer (score 1):

> I need the option to wait for all the
>   threads of a certain file to end

I did not understand your requirement clearly, but I think something like this will work for you:

```
// FileSender is the wrapper class you mentioned - where you keep track
// of file->threads association
public class FileSender {
    private final File file;

    private List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    public FileSender(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void addThread(Thread thread) {
        if (thread != null) {
            this.threads.add(thread);
        }
        for (Iterator<Thread> itr = threads.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            Thread t = itr.next();
            if (! t.isAlive()) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    // this method blocks until all threads associated with
    // this file has completed execution
    public void waitForCompletion() throws InterruptedException {

        for (Iterator<Thread> itr = threads.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            Thread thread = itr.next();
            thread.join();
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```